# How to POST to a webservice that doesn't accept SOAP

Tags: .net, saml, restsharp

I am currently trying to send a compiled token to the web service which requires the token but I am unable to do it using most .NET 4.5 classes.

Every time I send any sort of HTTP POST request to the server, it is unable to read the information i send to it as apparently they do not accept any sort of connection which includes a SOAP call.

I have actively tried to see how else I could contact the server without the SOAP call but only way I could find was by including the token inside the HTML and posting with Javascript. For obvious reasons I don't want to use this method as its not secure.

```
public void sendHTTPPost(string token)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
    var client = new RestClient("DOMAIN");
    var request = new RestRequest("URLEXTRA", Method.POST);
    var tokenToBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(token);
    string encodedToken = System.Convert.ToBase64String(tokenToBytes);
    request.AddParameter("TOKEN", encodedToken);
    var response = client.Execute(request);
    Response.Write(response.Content);
}
```

The server should be able to see the data but as mentioned, the server doesn't accept any POST methods with a SOAP binding.

Are there any other ways I would be able to contact this service via .NET without the use of the SOAP call/binding?

Comment: SOAP is just one of many conventions built atop HTTP. If the server is doing some form of HTTP, you need to find out *what conventions it's following*. We'll not be able to help you with discovering that - it'll be documentation for the server or a conversation with the maintainers of the server.

Answer (score 0):

If it expects a simple http post with a parameter you can use a WebRequest client in .net rather than rest client.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class